# Laravel Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel-5, jwt

Estoy haciendo un login JWT y en el momento de probar la ruta me arroja un error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

**routes.php**

```
 Route::group(['middleware'=>'cors'], function(){
    Route::post('/auth_login', 'ApiAuthController@userAuth');
});
```

**ApiAuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class ApiAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function userAuth(Request $requet){
        $credentials = $request->only('email','password');
        $token = null;
        try{
            if(!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
                return response()->json('error','invalid credentials');
            }

        }catch(JWTException $ex){
                return responsee()->json(['error'=>'somthing_went_worng'],500);
        }
   return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

¿A qué se debe este error?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás probando la ruta?

Comment: La pruebo con postman y el metodo es un post donde paso los parametros

Comment: El problema fue solucionado. No tenía agregada una libreria.

Comment: Puedes agregar una respuesta explicando la solución y especificando la librería y el código necesario, en caso que le pase a otro usuario.

Answer (score -1):

La solución fue la siguiente

Como se dan cuenta esto recibe una llamada request en la cual llegan algunas credenciales como mail y contraseña, pero la llamada es hacia el modelo User que es donde está vinculado los datos.  Por ende la solución es llamar a

```
use App\User;
```

Con solamente eso  se soluciono, la solución completa es

```
  <?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use JWTAuth;

use App\User;

class ApiAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function userAuth(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email','password');
        $token = null;
        $user = null;
        try{

            if(! $request->has('password')){
                $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

                if (empty($user)){
                    $user = User::create([
                        'name' => $request->input('name'),
                        'email' => $request->input('email'),
                        'avatar' => $request->input('avatar')
                    ]);
                }

                if(! $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)){
                        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 500);
                }

            }else{
                if(! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
                    return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 500);
                }
                $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
            }
        }catch(JWTException $ex){
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Something_went_error'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(compact('token', 'user'));
    }

}
```